# Python reading google search result with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I have the following code:

```
def downloadData(queryString):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(queryString) as url:
        encoding = url.headers.get_content_charset()
        result = url.read().decode(encoding)
    return result
```

However for google, which returns https documents, I get an error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Here is the query string:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Dow+Jones+Industrial+Average+Quote+with+volume
```

How would I need to change it to process https? Thank you!

Comment: Probably would help if you provide the `queryString` you're working with.

Comment: On a side note, you might want to look into the `requests` module. It is much easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set a user agent:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping