# Using python re.compile with beautiful soup to match a string

Tags: python, regex

I am wanting to find a url inside of returned http headers. According to [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) there is a way to use `soup.find_all(re.compile("yourRegex")` to collect the regex matches in an array. However, I must be missing something from my regex, which has a match in the regex find of the [text editor that I am using](https://atom.io/), but doesn't match insided of the following code:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import csv
import json
import time
import fileinput
import urllib2

```
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
stringSoup = str(soup)

#Trying to use compile 
print soup.find_all(re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?"))
```

I have tried putting `()` around the regex, as well as starting it with `r`...what am I missing that is necessary?

I've also been using http://www.pythonregex.com/, putting `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?` in the regex part and a url in the other part, but there's no match there either. 
Thanks!

Comment: what is the content of `stringsoup`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p8tu1e87/1/

Comment: re.match will any ways not give any result as it matches from start.you can try re.findall instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(?:com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)+(?:[\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?",x)
```

Try this.This works for me.

```
x="""<!DOCTYPE html>

<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">

<head>
"""
```

Output:`schema.org/QAPage`

Comment: @maudulus: `oh la la la`, you don't need to escape special characters in a character class except `-` unless it is at the end or the begining of the class. Writing something like `[&amp;]` DO NOT HAVE ANY SENSE, a character class is a collection of characters without order, it's the same than `[;p&ma]`.

Answer (score 0):

your regex has no problem but you dident got the concept. find_all only search in tag.
Example:
find_all("^b")   this will give u all tag that start with name b 
so output will be tag like p, tbody, body etc.. 
.If you put re.compile in find_all, it will look for pattern only in tag element not the whole html document.
you need to use the method explained by vks.