# Webscrape table from CME, including selection of desired table from drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The below code works.  It returns data in the default loaded table (making use of answer provided here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936918/webscraping-with-urllib/45938987#comment91483591_45938987), but how to access the other tables (that can be found by clicking on the 'Contracts' button and selecting from the menu a different contract, eg. Mar 2019)?

```
driver.get("http://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html")
# Need to include some more time here for data in iframe to load?
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
CMEtreasuryAnalytics._table = soup.select('table.grid')[0]
```

I tried this but get the following error returned: **NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame**

```
driver.get("http://www.cmegroup.com/tools-nformation/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html")
cDate = 'Dec 2018'
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("square-corners ")
options = [element.get_attribute("innerText") for element in elements] 
if cDate in options:
    element = elements[options.index(cDate)] 
else:
    pass
driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```

I've also tryed to 'click()' but couldn't get that to work either.  I'm new to selenium and would appreciate some pointers on how to access the said data. I'm using python and chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I worked it out.  The menu lies within the iFrame, 
so after getting the element details, then need to click() the menu, then element.click(), then scrape the displayed data.  The final code follows, but I don't know if it's the most straightforward way to approach it.

```
driver.get("http://www.cmegroup.com/tools-nformation/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html")
cDate = 'Jun 2019'
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("square-corners ")
options = [element.get_attribute("innerText") for element in elements] 
if cDate in options:
    element = elements[options.index(cDate)] 
else:
    pass            
# Click the dropdown menu labelled 'Contracts'
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedStrikeAsYield_ucContractPicker_ucTrigger_lnkTrigger"]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(1) 
element.click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
CMEtreasuryAnalytics._table = soup.select('table.grid')[0]
```

Update:
The above worked for a while but then started failing with the below message.  So maybe this is the right track but I need better way to select an option from the drop down list labelled 'Contracts'.  How to do that?
Message: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (511, 475). Other element would receive the click: <