# Web scraping issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a page but I keep getting an error message. "raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: Not Found".

Can anyone see why I am getting this issue and how I can fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
U="https://llis.nasa.gov/search?organization=arc&page=1"


uClient=uReq(U)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
page_soup.h2
```

Comment: please provide the stacktrace for error.

Comment: Replacing `urllib.request` with `urllib` in the imports works for me.

Comment: Could it be linked to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module as the more powerful and flexible for dealing with HTTP requests:

```
import bs4, requests

url = "https://llis.nasa.gov/search?organization=arc&page=1"
data = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.body)
```

The output:

```
<body>
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/llis.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way of passing bf over the webpage and scrapping off all the NASA lessons? For example: https://llis.nasa.gov/lesson/1347

Comment: @J.Smith, what does mean your *passing bf over the webpage*?

Comment: Let me rephrase it. I want all the information from the following webpage: https://www.transit.dot.gov/regulations-and-guidance/list-project-management-oversight-pmo-lessons-learned

Comment: Is it possible for Beautiful Soup to go and and collect all the information from different links on a single page? Or can you only scrape words from that one page?

Comment: @J.Smith, what does mean your *all the information from different links* - should it parse only `<a>` tag text values OR follow all the links and extract the whole web page presented by external link?