# HTML parsing forbidden error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
import urllib.request

url='''https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol='''
Stock = input('Enter the stock name: ').upper()
url = url + Stock
comp_info = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

I am getting forbidden error, not able to understand the issue with the code. I am trying to input ITC.

Comment: Hm, weird. I also can't open this URL with `request.urlopen` because of response code 403, but it works well with `requests.get()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP error 403 in Python 3 Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. Seems like this resource is trying to block bots in simplest manner (by checking if request was sent from browser or not).

You can set dummy [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) with appropriate [header](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html#headers) to solve this issue:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url, 
                                 headers={'User-Agent': 'Browser'}) 
urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: add this link for reference https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html#headers

Comment: thanks it worked, but i dont get what this code [request = urllib.request.Request(url, 
                                 headers={'User-Agent': 'Browser'})]  does... can you explain it in simple words

Comment: @RajatGarg this code is there to set HTTP header to Request object. Name of the header is "User-Agent", and value is "Browser" - just random string to emulate browsers behavior.  Probably you should read about User-Agent header and/or about HTTP headers in general.