# Python - Scraping with BeautifulSoup and Urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to read website, but unfortunately something is wrong.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://csgoempire.com/withdraw').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Informatika/Python3X/GamblinSitesBot/GamblingSitesBot.py", line 4, in <module>
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://csgoempire.com/').read()
  File "c:\users\edgaras\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\users\edgaras\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\users\edgaras\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\users\edgaras\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\users\edgaras\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\users\edgaras\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Moreover, this code works with other sites such as google.com

Comment: I don't think this is the entire stacktrace? if so, please provide the full error

Comment: Appears that URL requires authentication. Throws a 403 error.

Comment: Do u have any proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP error 403 in Python 3 Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve the same using request library. This works fine

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

sauce = requests.get('https://csgoempire.com/withdraw')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('p'))
```