# Downloading file on python gets http 403 forbidden

Tags: python-2.7, http-error

I've been trying to download a file from the link http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt using Python 2.7 but it keeps on saying:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)>
```

The code I am using is:

```
req = Request('http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping

Comment: you basically need to set user agent as a browser. the web server security settings usually bots

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `requests` and `fake-useragent`.

First, make sure you've got them installed using your command line:

```
pip install requests fake-useragent
```

Then use:

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua_str = UserAgent().chrome
url = "https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt"
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": ua_str})
txt = r.content
```

Answer (score 0):

Its another simple way to do it..

code:

```
import urllib2
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt", headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = page.read()
print content
```

sample Output:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])
     by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;
     Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.3
Received: from murder ([unix socket])
     by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.2.12) with LMTPA;
     Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
    by flawless.mail.umich.edu () with ESMTP id m05EEFR1013674;
    Sat, 5 Jan 2008 09:14:15 -0500
Received: FROM paploo.uhi.ac.uk (app1.prod.collab.uhi.ac.uk [194.35.219.184])
    BY holes.mr.itd.umich.edu ID 477F90B0.2DB2F.12494 ; 
     5 Jan 2008 09:14:10 -0500
Received: from paploo.uhi.ac.uk (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by paploo.uhi.ac.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5F919BC2F2;
    Sat,  5 Jan 2008 14:10:05 +0000 (GMT)
Message-ID: <200801051412.m05ECIaH010327@nakamura.uits.iupui.edu>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Received: from prod.collab.uhi.ac.uk ([194.35.219.182])
          by paploo.uhi.ac.uk (JAMES SMTP Server 2.1.3) with SMTP ID 899
          for <source@collab.sakaiproject.org>;
          Sat, 5 Jan 2008 14:09:50 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from nakamura.uits.iupui.edu (nakamura.uits.iupui.edu [134.68.220.122])
    by shmi.uhi.ac.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id A215243002
    for <source@collab.sakaiproject.org>; Sat,  5 Jan 2008 14:13:33 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from nakamura.uits.iupui.edu (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by nakamura.uits.iupui.edu (8.12.11.20060308/8.12.11) with ESMTP id m05ECJVp010329
    for <source@collab.sakaiproject.org>; Sat, 5 Jan 2008 09:12:19 -0500
Received: (from apache@localhost)
    by nakamura.uits.iupui.edu (8.12.11.20060308/8.12.11/Submit) id m05ECIaH010327
    for source@collab.sakaiproject.org; Sat, 5 Jan 2008 09:12:18 -0500
Date: Sat, 5 Jan 2008 09:12:18 -0500
X-Authentication-Warning: nakamura.uits.iupui.edu: apache set sender to stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za using -f
To: source@collab.sakaiproject.org
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
Subject: [sakai] svn commit: r39772 - content/branches/sakai_2-5-x/content-impl/impl/src/java/org/sakaiproject/content/impl
```

Hope it helps!!