# scraping links from a website with a 403 error python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-406

I am trying to scrape the links from a list of links (all to different pages on the same website), but I keep running a 403 error. Here is an example of a link I am trying to scrape

https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band

https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band

etc.

Here is my code:

```
getarticles = []

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for i in listoflinks:
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):

        getarticles.append(link['href'])
```

I've been trying to use some of the answers from [HTTP error 403 in Python 3 Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping) but I haven't had much success. I'm not sure if I'm applying them to my whole list of links correctly. I attempted to use one of the solutions below by using a header, but that returns a HTTP 406 error: not acceptable

Here is my code attempted to fix:

```
getarticles = []
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for i in listoflinks:
    req=urllib.request.Request(i, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):

        getarticles.append(link['href'])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm very new to this, so as much as you can explain and help is great. I'd just like to collect the links from my list of websites!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> [403 FORBIDDEN](https://httpstatuses.com/403)
>
> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> [406 NOT ACCEPTABLE](https://httpstatuses.com/406)
>
> The target resource does not have a current representation that would
>   be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive
>   negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is
>   unwilling to supply a default representation.

Your User-Agent might be the problem. I was able to get an output by changing it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
listoflinks=['https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band','https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band']
getarticles = []
for i in listoflinks:
    req = urllib.request.Request(
    i,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
    )
    resp= urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'),features="lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        getarticles.append(link['href'])
print(getarticles)
```

Output

```
['https://www.spectatornews.com/ads/banner-advertise-with-the-spectator/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/editorial-policy/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/correction-policy/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/bylaws/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/advertise/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/contact/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/submit-a-letter/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/submit-a-news-tip/', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/', '#', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ', 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news', 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/', 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews', 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2004/05/06/english-fest-draws-speakers-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2004/05/03/burgers-on-the-grill-bands-on-the-scene/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/29/hempfest-celebrates-its-10th-year-with-11-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/29/pat-mcgee-band-rocks-mad-town/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/22/leinenkugels-battle-of-the-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/08/on-the-music-scene-band-makes-mondays-better/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/03/18/on-the-music-scene-band-carries-on-duluozs-work/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/10/09/jamband-grooving-to-eau-claire/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/05/01/joepalooza-set-with-5-bands-one-drummer/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2003/05/01/hempfest-features-nine-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/02/17/houston-based-band-reaching-out-to-college-students-on-tour/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/02/06/minneapolis-band-trips-into-eau-claire/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/2/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/3/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/4/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/8/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/9/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/127/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/', '#', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ', 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news', 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/', 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews', 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews', '/', 'https://snosites.com/why-sno/', 'http://snosites.com', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/wp-login.php', '#top', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/ads/banner-advertise-with-the-spectator/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/editorial-policy/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/correction-policy/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/bylaws/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/advertise/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/contact/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/submit-a-letter/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/submit-a-news-tip/', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/', '#', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ', 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news', 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/', 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews', 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2004/05/06/english-fest-draws-speakers-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2004/05/03/burgers-on-the-grill-bands-on-the-scene/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/29/hempfest-celebrates-its-10th-year-with-11-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/29/pat-mcgee-band-rocks-mad-town/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/22/leinenkugels-battle-of-the-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/04/08/on-the-music-scene-band-makes-mondays-better/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2004/03/18/on-the-music-scene-band-carries-on-duluozs-work/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/10/09/jamband-grooving-to-eau-claire/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/05/01/joepalooza-set-with-5-bands-one-drummer/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2003/05/01/hempfest-features-nine-bands/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/02/17/houston-based-band-reaching-out-to-college-students-on-tour/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/02/06/minneapolis-band-trips-into-eau-claire/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/2/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/3/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/4/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/8/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/9/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/127/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/', '#', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ', 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news', 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/', 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews', 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews', '/', 'https://snosites.com/why-sno/', 'http://snosites.com', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/wp-login.php', '#top', '/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/']
```

**Edit to handle 404 errors:**

Some links in your list might be unavailable. One option is to use a try-except block to handle these and process the remaining links

So the final code would be

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
listoflinks=['https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band','https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band','https://www.spectatornews.com/page/100099?s=band','http://sdfgsdjhgfjsgdhfgsj.com']
getarticles = []
for i in listoflinks:
    req = urllib.request.Request(
    i,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
    )
    try:
        resp= urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404:
            print("Unavailable link",i," skipping---")
        else:
            raise e
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'),features="lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        getarticles.append(link['href'])
print(getarticles)
```

Comment: hmmm for some reason it still isn't working. With your code I return a 404 error. Any other ideas? thank you for trying!

Comment: I was finally able to find my user agent, and that change fixed it. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I will also try using your edit if the issue continues on other pages. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say upfront that I rarely ever use the urllib/3 library.  I did, however, try using scrapy's shell terminal command as well as using the request library with no user agent and got the 200 response.

I did notice that you didn't declare the type of parser when declaring "soup".

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
```

Though I am much more comfortable using scrapy's parser, despite it being heavier, but if remember correctly you must declare a parser type, for example

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "lxml")
```

Bitto Benni-chan says he managed to get it to respond with 200 urllib.request so try his changes. Which was just inputting the full user agent name.

My suggestion would be is to use the request library. would be simple a simple enough change I think.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

listoflinks = ['https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band', 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band']

getarticles = []

for i in listoflinks:
    resp = requests.get(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "lxml")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):

        getarticles.append(link['href'])
```

the getarticles list outputted this:

```
'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/showcase/2003/02/06/minneapolis-band-trips-into-eau-claire/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/showcase/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/2/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/3/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/4/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/8/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/9/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/127/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/7/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/',
 '#',
 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ',
 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news',
 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/',
 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews',
 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews',
 '/',
 'https://snosites.com/why-sno/',
 'http://snosites.com',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/wp-login.php',
 '#top',
 '/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/ads/banner-advertise-with-the-spectator/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/',
 '/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/editorial-policy/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/correction-policy/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/about/bylaws/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/advertise/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/contact/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/submit-a-letter/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/submit-a-news-tip/',
 '/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/',
 '/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/',
 '#',
 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ',
 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news',
 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/',
 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews',
 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2002/05/09/late-night-bus-service-idea-abandoned-due-to-expense/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/opinion/2002/03/21/yates-deserved-what-she-got-husband-also-to-blame/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/opinion/2001/11/29/air-force-concert-band-inspires-zorn-arena-audience/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2001/10/25/goth-style-bands-will-entertain-at-halloween-costume-concert/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2001/04/19/campus-group-will-host-hemp-event-with-bands-information/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/currents/2018/12/10/geekin-out/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/currents/2018/12/10/geekin-out/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Alanna%20Huggett',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/geekcon/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/tv10/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/uwec/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/opinion/2018/12/07/keeping-up-with-the-kar-fashions-11/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/opinion/2018/12/07/keeping-up-with-the-kar-fashions-11/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Kar%20Wei%20Cheng',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/column-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/accessories/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/fashion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/multimedia/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/winter/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/multimedia-2/2018/12/07/a-magical-night/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/multimedia-2/2018/12/07/a-magical-night/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Julia%20Van%20Allen',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/dancing/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/harry-potter/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/smom/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/student-ministry-of-magic/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/uwec/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/yule/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/yule-ball/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2018/11/26/old-news-5/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/campus-news/2018/11/26/old-news-5/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Madeline%20Fuerstenberg',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/column-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/1950/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/1975/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/2000/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/articles/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/spectator/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/throwback/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/currents/2018/11/21/boss-women-highlighting-businesswomen-in-eau-claire-6/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/currents/2018/11/21/boss-women-highlighting-businesswomen-in-eau-claire-6/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Taylor%20Reisdorf',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/column-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/altoona/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/boss-women/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/business-women/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/cherish-woodford/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/crossfit/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/crossfit-river-prairie/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/eau-claire/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/fitness/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/gym/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/local/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/nicole-randall/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/river-prairie/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/currents/2018/11/20/bad-art-good-music/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/currents/2018/11/20/bad-art-good-music/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Lea%20Kopke',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/bad-art/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/fmdown/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/ghosts-of-the-sun/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/music/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/pablo-center/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/opinion/2018/11/14/the-tator-21/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/opinion/2018/11/14/the-tator-21/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/staff/?writer=Stephanie%20Janssen',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/column-2/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/satire/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/sleepy/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/tator/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/uw-eau-claire/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/tag/uwec/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/2/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/3/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/4/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/5/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/6/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/8/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/9/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/10/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/127/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/page/8/?s=band',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/feed/rss/',
 '#',
 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1SM8q3lk_fQS1KuY77bDgQ',
 'https://www.snapchat.com/add/spectator news',
 'https://www.instagram.com/spectatornews/',
 'http://twitter.com/spectatornews',
 'http://facebook.com/spectatornews',
 '/',
 'https://snosites.com/why-sno/',
 'http://snosites.com',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/wp-login.php',
 '#top',
 '/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/campus-news/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/currents/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/sports/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/opinion/',
 'https://www.spectatornews.com/category/multimedia-2/']
```