# Webscraping a power BI table from webpage as practice using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, datatable

For context, I'm trying to get a sense on webscraping using Python to collect any type of website data. I'm using it for a homework project where I'm highlighting population covered by recycling facility in the US, crosswalking locations on that page to Census Total Pop by ZIP code for those 25mile surrounding each site.

I've found [Edureka's tutorial](https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/) and many others.

With below code, I've managed to parse this html, thanks to royatirek's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/problem-http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping) as it was giving me HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url="https://recyclingpartnership.org/residential-mrfs/"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
```

I'm not familiar with any html or webscraping at all, so when I click on inspect to find the data table section.

Tried finding 'table' or something similar IDs with no luck on that, so I'm stuck at this point. Could someone kindly point out how to collect a data table as this?